# Installing Ladder in Historic Brick Garage

Tags: garage, attic, joists, structural, brick

Just bought an old home with a detached 1905 brick garage w/ loft. Currently, the only way to access the space is by pulling out a ladder and climbing through a 16" opening at the end. I'd like to install a ladder for easier access to ultimately build out a loft space. Garage specs, specific questions, and photos below:

**Garage Specs**

- 3 layers of brick
- 17'9" by 19'4"
- 12 joists running horizontally (19'4"). Joists are 2x8s w/ 14" between them
- Joists run strait into the brick -- not connecting to the roof trusses which run into the brick 2' above
- Garage attic has electrical, window, and work benches. Appears to have been used (but not receently)

**My Questions**

1. Any concerns about structural integrity from what you read/see? Do I need to consider reinforcing the current joists?
2. What are my options for installing a ladder? I could cut/reinforce one joist and install an attic ladder, but would love something that provides even easier access. Is it possible to cut a corner and install a small spiral staircase? Would love other ideas for easy access without taking up too much garage space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could install [alternating tread stairs](https://www.lapeyrestair.com/products/alternating-tread-stairs). Good side: small footprint, treads rather than rungs offer better footing, stable and sturdy. Bad side: you have to get off on the right foot, not easy to carry bulky items, steep. (Check with your local code authority to see if they are permitted for your application.) Someone even made a spiral version: [gallery](https://www.pinterest.com/sejmap/alternating-tread-stairs-and-mezzanines/).

Comment: Please consult a structural engineer, as there are risks and coded rules for renovation, and alteration involving such old building.

Comment: Build (or buy) an external staircase (spiral if you like) and take up no garage space at all, if the LAHJ and/or Historical Building rules (if any apply) permit. Odd to have that much space, window, and workbenches with such limited access; leads one to think of nefarious historical activities taking place up there.